# Run echo and redirect it to cat with dash shell

Tags: bash, makefile, echo, cat, dash-shell

I want make one-liner that creates zipped file with python code. However when I run it in Makefile, it uses the default shell (dash). Is the

```
bash$ dash
dash$ zip --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '*.swp' --exclude '*.pyc' --exclude 'tool' --exclude Makefile -r - . | cat <(echo '#!/usr/bin/env python') - > externaltool
dash: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
dash$ exit
```

But in bash it works perfectly well

```
bash$ zip --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '*.swp' --exclude '*.pyc' --exclude 'externaltool' --exclude Makefile -r - . | cat <(echo '#!/usr/bin/env python') - > externaltool
  adding: common/ (stored 0%)
  adding: common/config.py (deflated 19%)
  adding: common/cmdwrap.py (deflated 65%)
  adding: common/extconfig.py (deflated 71%)
  adding: common/commands.py (deflated 19%)
  adding: common/__init__.py (stored 0%)
  adding: __main__.py (deflated 45%)
```

Is there any method to express *cat <(echo '#!/usr/bin/env python') -* in dash ?

I know I can add to Makefile

```
SHELL := /bin/bash
```

but it is just workaround rather than pernament solution.

Comment: What's this got to  do with bash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. dash doesn't support [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution).

But that's also a rather strange way to do what you want there.

Two simpler (and dash compatible unless I'm sorely mistaken) ways are:

```
{ echo '#!/usr/bin/env python'; zip --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '*.swp' --exclude '*.pyc' --exclude 'tool' --exclude Makefile -r - .; } > externaltool
```

and

```
echo '#!/usr/bin/env python' > externaltool
zip --exclude '.git/*' --exclude '*.swp' --exclude '*.pyc' --exclude 'tool' --exclude Makefile -r - . >> externaltool`
```